# C stat() function reports that Windows Desktop folder is read-only

Tags: windows, desktop, stat

Obviously, my desktop is not read-only, however stat() and findfirst() functions report this as non-writable. Should I use some other function instead? Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    PWSTR ppszPath;
    if (::SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &ppszPath)==S_OK) {
        std::wcout << L"Desktop folder: " << ppszPath << L"\n";
        struct _stat64 buf;
        if (_wstat64(ppszPath, &buf)==0) {
            std::wcout << L"Writable: " << ( (buf.st_mode & _S_IWRITE) != 0? "yes": "no") << L"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out on Windows7 x64:

```
Desktop folder: C:\Users\heldepn\Desktop
Writable: no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "read-only" flag for directories is decorative and [does not control whether the directory contents can be modified](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/30/55100.aspx). Creating files in a directory is controlled by `FILE_ADD_FILE`, deleting files in a directory is controlled by `FILE_DELETE_CHILD`, and creating a subdirectory is controlled by `FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`.

Comment: Thanks, I would have expected to find this info in the documentation of stat() as this deviates from the corresponding Posix behavior, but obviously this is too much to want.

Comment: The Windows security model is more complex than Posix, so any mapping is necessarily incomplete. The `stat` function is extra-lazy and just uses the file attributes.

Comment: One minor clarification: the read-only flag is not entirely decorative, it does prevent the directory from being removed.